# Why this round get different result?

Tags: python-3.x

When I use the round, it should be get a same result, the first code seems failed to round it? why?

```
clf = classify(features_train, labels_train)
acc = accuracy_score(clf.predict(features_test), labels_test)
def submitAccuracies():
    return {"acc": round(acc, 3)}
print(submitAccuracies())
print("acc: ", round(acc, 3))
```

myoutput:

```
{'acc': 0.91200000000000003}
acc:  0.912
```

Comment: What version of python are you using. I get the same output in Python 3.6

Comment: yes, this is Python 3.6.

Comment: Not able to reproduce it on my end it get `{'acc': 0.912}
acc:  0.912`

Comment: If I just use 0.9120000003 as a input, I can get the right output. I think there must be something wrong in my function...